# How can I replicate the VariableSizedWrapGrid XAML control in HTML5/JS Metro app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

There is a XAML Control called the VariableSizedWrapGrid which neatly arranges different size items within it.

"Provides a grid-style layout panel where each tile/cell can be variable size based on content"

Unfortunately this control is not available in WinJS, only XAML, but I would like to replicate it. Any ideas on how this would best be replicated in an HTML5/JS Metro app?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh969155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinJS.UI.ListView control supports "Variable Sized" items, but it's quite complex (Details at the end of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781224.aspx)).

However, at a more basic layout level, you can try using a flex box. I dont think it's quite the same match for layout, but it should enable you to get close. Details on the different patterns is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh673531.aspx), and a nice hands-on is [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_flex.htm) (view in IE)